# Shuffling method in c++ returning absurd cards

Tags: c++, c++17, shuffle

Been following project tutorials and wanted to add my own shuffle method, the output is correct however once I use my shuffle method I get ridiculous values for two spades, for ex. (-68218624 of spades) or (32762 of spades) everything else outputs fine. Trying to figure out whats wrong.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum class Suits{
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
    Hearts,
    Spades
};

enum class Names{
    Two = 2,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace
};

struct Card{
    Names name;
    Suits suit;
    int value;    
    
    void printCard(){
        printValue();

        cout << " of ";

        printSuit();
        
        cout << endl;
    }

    void printValue(){

        cout << value;

    }

    void printSuit(){
        if(suit == Suits::Clubs){
            cout << "clubs";
        }
        else if(suit == Suits::Diamonds){
            cout << "diamonds";
        }
        else if(suit == Suits::Hearts){
            cout << "hearts";
        }
        else{
            cout << "spades";
        }
    }

};

struct Deck{
    Card arrCards[52];

    void printCards(){
         for(int col = (int)Suits::Clubs; col <= (int)Suits::Spades; col++){
            for(int row = (int)Names::Two; row <= (int)Names::King; row++){  

                int index = (13 * col) + row -1;

                arrCards[index].printCard();
            }
        }
    }

    void SetupCards(){
        for(int col = (int)Suits::Clubs; col <= (int)Suits::Spades; col++){
            for(int row = (int)Names::Two; row <= (int)Names::King; row++){
                Card c;
                c.suit = (Suits)col;
                c.name = (Names)row;
                c.value = (int)c.name;    

                int index = (13 * col) + row -1;

                arrCards[index] = c;
            }
        }
    }

    int deckSize(){
        return sizeof(arrCards)/sizeof(arrCards[0]);

    }

    
    void shuffleDeck(Card deck[], int length){

        Card temp;
        int randomIndex = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            randomIndex = rand() % (length);
            temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[randomIndex];
            deck[randomIndex] = temp;

        }
    }
};

int main(){
    Deck deck;

    cout << endl;
    
    deck.SetupCards();

   deck.printCards();

   cout << "The deck has this many cards: " << deck.deckSize() << endl;

    deck.shuffleDeck(deck.arrCards, deck.deckSize());

    deck.printCards();

    cout << endl;
}
```

// output after shuffle method example:
5 of spades
5 of clubs
7 of diamonds
32762 of spades
11 of clubs

Comment: Have you turned on all compiler warnings? Random values like you indicate typically point to uninitialized variables.

Comment: `sizeof(arrCards)/sizeof(arrCards[0]);` is an antipattern in modern C++.  You should use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) instead.

Comment: Double check this index calculation, keeping in mind that your array starts at 0: `int index = (13 * col) + row -1;`

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger to see where the printed values came from?

Comment: Side note: [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: [Rubber duckie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know why you are passing members of a class instance into a member function invoked on the same instance.

Comment: Learn about `std::vector`, `std::array`, `std::span`, `std::shuffle`, constructors, `operator <<` overloading, `std::swap`. Why have name and value? They are the same. Why aren't name/suite/value const?

Comment: Your shuffle algorithm seems simple enough but it's actually broken. See [here](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/2744-how-not-to-shuffle-the-kunth-fisher-yates-algorithm.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(int row = (int)Names::Two; row <= (int)Names::King; row++){
```

You only initialized 48 of the cards.  You hit all four suits, but you only initialize ranks 2 through King.  The last four slots in the 52-card array are uninitialized.

Comment: Actually, since `Names::Two` has the value 2, the smallest index written to is `(13 * 0) + 2 - 1 = 1`, i.e. the first and the last 3 "slots" remain uninitialized...

Comment: You're right.  He's writing cards into invalid indexes beyond the end of arrCards[].